# Generated SEO article / read-more links invalid

Tags: php, url, joomla

I updated my old joomla 1.5 website to joomla 2.5.8. It forced me to update some modules and plugins, and I finally thought I had everything working.

As the final step, I activated the SEO urls. Although the website and the menu still works, there are few locations where there are links generated, that don't work anymore.

Eg: on the homepage, I have a list of articles with an intro text. These have the normal "read more" link. This link stops working when the SEO is enabled.

It should link to:
    http://www.domain.com/home/4-nieuws/289-article-alias-test
but it links to:
http://www.domain.com/?id=289:article-alias-test

This also happens with the links below the article list, that link to other articles inside the same category.

I traced the faulty code, and it is located in components/com_content/views/category/tmpl/blog_links.php

This is the content of the file:

```
    <?php
/**
 * @package     Joomla.Site
 * @subpackage  com_content
 * @copyright   Copyright (C) 2005 - 2012 Open Source Matters, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * @license     GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
 */

// no direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
?>


<div class="items-more">

<h3><?php echo JText::_('COM_CONTENT_MORE_ARTICLES'); ?></h3>
<ol>
<?php
    foreach ($this->link_items as &$item) :
?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getArticleRoute($item->slug, $item->catid)); ?>">
            <?php echo $item->title; ?></a>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ol>
</div>
```

I did not change any code in this file. Any suggestions on what might have caused this , and more importantly, how to fix it ?

Comment: The code seems fine to me. Check again if your menu structure is ok

Comment: What could be wrong with the menu structure, what exactly should I check ? The menu is displayed ok, I don't see any errors or similar.

Comment: Something probably went wrong during the upgrade, but it's not easy to see what, even though everything appears to be ok. For example, try rebuilding the menu structure, you will see a `rebuild` button when you open menu manager

Comment: I succesfully rebuilt the menu structure, but it did not solve the issue.

Comment: Eh, I hope someone else might have an idea...

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted looks absolutely fine. Sounds to me like you haven't renamed htaccess.txt to .htaccess which is required for SEF links to work. You can find it in your Joomla root directory.

If you already have done that it could also be a template override from Joomla 1.5 left in your template. You can find the overrides in /templates/YOURTEMPLATE/html/

Comment: The htaccess is active, since the SEO urls in the menu work fine. The code above is not overridden. If I change it slightly, for example, add a '!' after the title, it is visible on the website.

Comment: To clarify: translating the SEO url back into a viewable webpage works fine. The problem is in the "generating the SEO url"-part.

Comment: I see. Are you using Joomla core SEF links or a 3rd party SEF links extension?

Comment: The default joomla core SEF. No 3rd party SEF installed.